# How to Array Assignment

Tags: numpy

I have an image with (128,19,3) dimension(which its name is frame_0). i create a 5D zeros tensor (which its name is e) and wants to add the image to the  e[0,0] but i got below error. thanks if any one can help

Error:

TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

image_folder = 'D:\\thesis\\Paper 3\\Feature Extraction\\two_dimension_Feature_extraction\\stft_feature\\Training_set\\P300'


images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".png")]
frame_0 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
e = np.zeros((1100,5,128,19,3),dtype=np.uint8)
e[0,0]=frame_0
```

Comment: Code works for me for some toy example. Please provide the whole stack trace. I'd guess the error occurs somewhere else, not in the given code segment.

Comment: Yes. you are right. error was for somewhere else. thanks for your help

Comment: The assignment instruction looks fine, thus I'd guess frame_0 has different shape than you expect. Try printing it out.